# CSINodes problem in Kubernetes Multiple Scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I try to create multiple scheduler running on kubernetes following this instruction https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
the new kubernetes scheduler status is **running** but the logs generate this error, and the pods that using the new scheduler status is **pending**

```
E1129 02:43:22.639372       1 reflector.go:156] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135: Failed to list *v1.CSINode: the server could not find the requested resource
```

and this is my clusterrole of kube-scheduler

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-28T08:29:43Z"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: system:kube-scheduler
  resourceVersion: "74398"
  selfLink: /apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/clusterroles/system%3Akube-scheduler
  uid: 517e8769-911c-4833-a37c-254edf49cbaa
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  - events.k8s.io
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - kube-scheduler
  - my-scheduler
  resources:
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - delete
  - get
  - patch
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - delete
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - bindings
  - pods/binding
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/status
  verbs:
  - patch
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - replicationcontrollers
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  - extensions
  resources:
  - replicasets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - statefulsets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resources:
  - poddisruptionbudgets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - persistentvolumes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - authentication.k8s.io
  resources:
  - tokenreviews
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - subjectaccessreviews
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - storage.k8s.io
  resources:
  - csinodes
  verbs:
  - watch
  - list
  - get
```

is there any suggestion of this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you use a copy of a default scheduler as in example described in  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/ or some other custom scheduler ?

Comment: yes i use the default scheduler as in example. I didn't change at all

Comment: finally I try to use the old version of kubernetes before 16.3, I am using 15.6 and it works now

Answer (score 1):

> finally I try to use the old version of kubernetes before 16.3, I am
>   using 15.6 and it works now – akhmad alimudin

OK, now I understand what was the cause of the issue you experienced. You probably tried to run newer `kube-scheduler` version on the a bit older k8s cluster (where the key component is `kube-apiserver`) which cannot be done. As you can read in the [official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kube-controller-manager-kube-scheduler-and-cloud-controller-manager):

> `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, and `cloud-controller-manager`
>   **must not be newer** than the `kube-apiserver` instances they communicate
>   with. They are expected to match the `kube-apiserver` **minor version**, but
>   may be up to one minor version older (to allow live upgrades).
>
> Example:
>
> `kube-apiserver` is at **1.13** `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, and
>   `cloud-controller-manager` are supported at **1.13** and **1.12**

So you can use `kube-scheduler` which is one minor version older than your currently deployed `kube-apiserver` but not newer.

Answer (score 0):

@mario is right, I hit the same issue, my original kubernates version is v1.16.3 and I use Scheduler-Framework of k8s which is v1.17.x.

I test my new scheduler on another k8s cluster with v1.17.x, it could work.