# problems with configure multiple schedulers in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

scheduler as custom scheduler by https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/configure-multiple-schedulers/.
And, I bind my ServiceAccount kube-system:my-scheduler with ClusterRole cluster-admin. My my-scheduler.yaml shows next.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler-as-kube-scheduler
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

And, my-scheduler pod can successfully run.  When I deploy pods that I schedule with the .spec.schedulerName set to my-scheduler, the pod wasn't scheduled. And the pod is **pending** status.
I checked the my-scheduler pod log using  kubectl logs -f my-scheduler-8699f6f86-vvn5p -n kube-system command. And the error info describes as following. I don't know why my-scheduler Failed to watch *v1.CSIStorageCapacity.

```
W1108 07:05:16.968419       1 reflector.go:424] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:149: failed to list *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: the server could not find the requested resource
E1108 07:05:16.968443       1 reflector.go:140] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:149: Failed to watch *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: failed to list *v1.CSIStorageCapacity: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Can anyone figure out the solution to the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099217/csinodes-problem-in-kubernetes-multiple-scheduler

Comment: @HarshManvar hi, the components in the my k8s cluster are compatible. The kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, and cloud-controller-manager are not be newer than the kube-apiserver instances they communicate with. Maybe the reason [solution link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099217/csinodes-problem-in-kubernetes-multiple-scheduler) is not the cause for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The versions of k8s components in my k8s cluster are shown next. I am sure that it's not incompatibleness between k8s components to result the problem.

```
[root@compileHost pluginsDir]# kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'apiserver'
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-apiserver@sha256:d10db42c2353539ce15006854edfb6707ba6025f282d59d962729ed3b6039004
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-apiserver:v1.23.0
```

```
[root@compileHost pluginsDir]# kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'kubelet'
      message: kubelet has sufficient memory available
      reason: KubeletHasSufficientMemory
      message: kubelet has no disk pressure
      reason: KubeletHasNoDiskPressure
      message: kubelet has sufficient PID available
      reason: KubeletHasSufficientPID
      message: kubelet is posting ready status
      reason: KubeletReady
      kubeletEndpoint:
      kubeletVersion: v1.23.0
      message: kubelet has sufficient memory available
      reason: KubeletHasSufficientMemory
      message: kubelet has no disk pressure
      reason: KubeletHasNoDiskPressure
      message: kubelet has sufficient PID available
      reason: KubeletHasSufficientPID
      message: kubelet is posting ready status
      reason: KubeletReady
      kubeletEndpoint:
      kubeletVersion: v1.23.0
[root@compileHost pluginsDir]# kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'kube-controller-manager'
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-controller-manager@sha256:0bfbb13e5e9cec329523b6f654687af8ce058adbc90b42e5af7a929ac22e2a53
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-controller-manager:v1.23.0
[root@compileHost pluginsDir]# kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -i 'kube-scheduler'
      - k8s.gcr.io/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler@sha256:880fb6f6b4bfa0d229d317c2f223313e3334ac013b6697a797bb16584d57f7c7
      - k8s.gcr.io/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler:v0.23.10
      - localhost:5000/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler:latest
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-scheduler@sha256:af8166ce28baa7cb902a2c0d16da865d5d7c892fe1b41187fd4be78ec6291c23
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-scheduler:v1.23.0
      - localhost:5000/scheduler-plugins/my-kube-scheduler:1.0
      - k8s.gcr.io/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler@sha256:880fb6f6b4bfa0d229d317c2f223313e3334ac013b6697a797bb16584d57f7c7
      - k8s.gcr.io/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler:v0.23.10
      - localhost:5000/scheduler-plugins/kube-scheduler:latest
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-scheduler@sha256:af8166ce28baa7cb902a2c0d16da865d5d7c892fe1b41187fd4be78ec6291c23
      - registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/kube-scheduler:v1.23.0
      - localhost:5000/scheduler-plugins/my-kube-scheduler:1.0
```

Comment: Maybe I know the cause for the problem. In the [Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/), we can see that info **Migrate manifests and API clients to use the storage.k8s.io/v1 API version, available since v1.24**. 
In other words, if the version of your k8s cluster is lower than v1.24,  you can not use the storage.k8s.io/v1 CSIStorageCapacity in your k8s cluster. However, the version of my k8s cluster is v1.23. So the kube-apiserver component in my k8s cluster can't find the requested resource **v1.CSIStorageCapacity**.

Comment: I will update my k8s cluster to upper version higher than v1.24, after this, I will attempt to schedule pods with my-scheduler. I will give some feedback on my later experiments.